# Flat Terrain Generation in Java

Tags: java, terrain

I am currently working on a 2D survival game and I want to generate my own custom terrain problem is, I don't know how! I wanted to make it similar to [Minicraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicraft) (not minecraft) where it is random flat terrain but i have no clue how to do so. I tried making sense of Notch's actual code but it all seems like gibberish.

If anyone could link me to a tutorial or at least explain how to do it please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11556441/230513) `implements Icon` and uses `TexturePaint` to synthesize ground tiles.

[image]