# Active rendering on a JPanel with ImageIcon tiles? #Java

Tags: java, swing, rendering, thread-sleep, game-loop

So I'm trying to write a tile-grid based game and came up with a quite unusual solution. I filled a 2D JPanel Array with JLabels with an ImageIcon as tile. Everything works so far but I did not find any way to render this activly.
I've tryied some methods for active rendering I found on the Internet, but they did not work on my idea. Do you have some ideas how to realize this without rewrite everything to Canvas or something similar?

Here's my code:

Window

```
public class Win extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private BufferStrategy bs;

public Win(int x, int y) {

    this.setSize(x, y);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    this.createBufferStrategy(2);
    setBs(getBufferStrategy());
}

public BufferStrategy getBs() {
    return bs;
}

public void setBs(BufferStrategy bs) {
    this.bs = bs;
}
}
```

"Draw"

```
public class Field extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5257799495742189076L;

private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
private JPanel backPanel[][] = new JPanel[19][19];
private BufferedImage images[] = new BufferedImage[100];
private JLabel image[][] = new JLabel[19][19];

public Field() {

    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 20));
    this.setIgnoreRepaint(true);

}

// Creates Panel Grid & Draws floor
public void setPanels() {
    for (int h = 0; h < 19; h++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < 19; w++) {

            backPanel[h][w] = new JPanel();
            backPanel[h][w].setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

            image[h][w] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(images[0]));

            backPanel[h][w].add(image[h][w]);

            this.add(backPanel[h][w]);
        }
    }
}

// Loads the Textures
public void getTextures() throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        images[i] = ImageIO.read(new File("texture.png"));

    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(images[1], 0, 0, null);

}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

}
```

Game Loop

```
public class GameLoop implements Runnable {

private boolean runFlag = true;

@Override
public void run() {
    Field field = new Field();
    Win window = new Win(640, 640);
    window.add(field);

    try {
        field.getTextures();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (runFlag) {

        try {
            field.setPanels();
            window.getBs().show();
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public void stop() {
    runFlag = false;
}

}
```

Comment: (search here for) use Swing Timer instead of Runnable blocked by Thread.sleep(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some alternatives:

- Shuffle the *components* and do `removeAll()`, `add()`, and `validate()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513).
- Shuffle the *contents* and do `setIcon()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

In either case,

- Use [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to pace the animation, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).
- Consider `TexturePaint` to fill the icons, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11553461/230513).

Comment: Repaint ist working now with removeAll() and validate() but its flickering now. Working on it. Ty :)